# Dynamically include all controllers, filters, services, etc in separate files AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have followed the advice to separate out my controllers, filters, services, etc into separate files as in [huge-angular-apps](http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps)
However this will result in a long list of script includes which requires editing when new components are added.

eg.

```
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/init.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/AController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/BController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/CController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/DController.js"></script>
  ...
```

Is it possible to dynamically include these components?

Comment: There are quite a few options, what technology are you using on your server? (node/ASP.Net)

Comment: `require js` you can use.

Comment: You can separate all the modules and then use grunt to concat all files and the minify it using the same grunt build file or create logic to lazy load modules using require.js

Comment: Personally I use grunt with the watch task. So basically I have all my controllers and so on in separate files, generally in a source directory, and inside my actual application I have a single JS file which is build by grunt. After good test framework handle file location syntax so everything can be tested using the untouched source files.

Comment: For requirejs option see https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed

Comment: Use this https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-injector I have implemented this in my personal angular boilerplate. Might help as a reference. https://github.com/blessenm/ng-app-kit

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at require fist before checking out grunt.